# How to fetch the mail in ews by giving the start date and end date

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am very new to EWS mail related topic. My task is to fetch all the mails between 2 dates.

I have tried couple other approach but didn't achieve as expected.

```
SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, greaterthanfilter);
```

How can we fetch the mail from EWS mail server by giving start date and end date?

Comment: you can easily get the code snippet, by writing it. SO is not a service to deliver custom made code, rather a platform that helps you improve your code

Comment: _I have tried couple other approach_ - Which was the best one? Can you show us so we have something to start from.

Comment: @Stultuske Using SearchFilter I tried but couldn't able to write complete logic to fetch mails. If I could get the logic to fetch mail using SearchFilter it would greate.

SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, greaterthanfilter);

Comment: @Karthiktn See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740707/how-to-fetch-the-mail-in-ews-by-giving-the-start-date-and-end-date#comment92407184_52740707) is in the right direction:

```
protected FindItemsResults<Item> getEmailsInTimeRange(ExchangeService service, Date from, Date to) throws Exception {
    ItemView view = new ItemView(128);
    SearchFilter fromFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, from);
    SearchFilter toFilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, to);
    SearchFilter inRangeFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, fromFilter, toFilter);
    FindItemsResults<Item> items = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, inRangeFilter, view);
    return items;
}
```

But **remember**:

> The FindItem operation returns only the first 512 bytes of any
>   streamable property. For Unicode, it returns the first 255 characters
>   by using a null-terminated Unicode string. It does not return any of
>   the message body formats or the recipient lists. FindItem will return
>   a recipient summary. You can use the `GetItem` Operation to get the
>   details of an item.

Source: MS Doc [FindItem Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa566107(v%3Dexchg.140))

If you need properties which aren't returned, then it's better to restrict the request to return only the IDs of the items. This will potentially speedup the server side processing since there is only the `ItemSchema.Id` to return for each `Item`.

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(128);
view.setPropertySet(PropertySet.IdOnly);
```

Now iterate over `FindItemsResults<Item> items`:

```
for (Item item : items) {
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId(), propertySet);
    // process the email
}
```

The `propertySet` should contain only the properties you need to read.

Comment: Hi @LuCio, Thanks for your valuable time and answer provided. When I try to implement above given code and run i am getting exception. 
java.lang.Exception: Validation failed. searchFilter
 at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.EwsUtilities.validateParamAllowNull(EwsUtilities.java:954)
 at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.folder.Folder.findItems(Folder.java:438)
Can you please tell me why I am getting this ?

Comment: @Karthiktn I've updated my answer. The filters `fromFilter` and `toFilter` need to be initialized with the property and the respective value.

Comment: Hi @LuCio, I took the latest modified code, but result is not as expected. I have 4 mail between 10/10/2018(fromDate) and 11/10/2018(toDate) dates , but result I am getting only 1 mail which is of date 10/10/2018. I have used below code 

 SF fromFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, date1);      
SF toFilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, date2);
SearchFilter inRangeFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, fromFilter, toFilter);
Could you please have look into it once. Thank you

Comment: I've run the code and I'm getting the emails returned I expect. Are you sure you're seeing `DateTimeReceived` and not `DateTimeCreated` or `DateTimeSent`?